# SpringBoot and Mybatis-plus andWebsocket Qusetion

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket, mybatis-plus

When I create a connection via websocket, I want to find the user's information from the database and store it in "friendsList" but when I call "getUserByUid" via "userMapper", it gives me null.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyiEz.png)
"CKt3z2RW6s" is uid.

I tried to put "userMapper.getUserByUid()" in another method, and receive it through the User object.
This is my code

```
package com.chat.imbackend.controller;


import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.chat.imbackend.entity.Friends;
import com.chat.imbackend.entity.Messages;
import com.chat.imbackend.entity.User;
import com.chat.imbackend.mapper.UserMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;


@Slf4j
@Component
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/{uid}")
public class WebSocketController {
    private Session session;


    @Autowired
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    /**
     * 好友列表
     */
    public static List<Friends> friendsList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * 定义并发HashMap存储好友WebSocket集合
     */
    public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, WebSocketController> webSocketSession = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(@PathParam(value = "uid") String uid, Session session) {
        // 设置session
        this.session = session;
        // Put添加当前类
        webSocketSession.put(uid, this);
        try {
            System.out.println(uid);
            User user = userMapper.getUserByUid(uid);
            // Add添加当前好友信息
            friendsList.add(Friends.builder().uid(uid).nickname(user.getNickname()).avatar(user.getAvatar()).build());
            // 通知更新好友信息列表
            updateFriendInformationList();

            log.info("【WebSocket消息】有新的连接[{}], 连接总数:{}", uid, webSocketSession.size());

        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * 通知更新好友信息列表
     */
    private synchronized void updateFriendInformationList() {
        webSocketSession.forEach((key, val) -> {
            // 初始化存储属于自己的好友列表 排除自己
            List<Friends> friends = new ArrayList<>();
            // 迭代所有好友列表
            friendsList.forEach((friend) -> {
                // 在 所有好友信息列表 中验证非自己
                if (!friend.getUid().equals(key)) {
                    // 追加非自己的好友信息
                    friends.add(friend);
                }
            });
            // 发送消息
            sendP2PMessage(key, JSON.toJSONString(Messages.builder().type("updateFriendsList").receiveUid(key).messages(friends).build()));
        });
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(@PathParam(value = "uid") String uid, String message) {
        log.info("【WebSocket消息】 收到客户端[{}] 发送消息:{} 连接总数:{}", uid, message, webSocketSession.size());

        // 验证消息内容
        if (StringUtils.hasLength(message)) {
            try {
                // 消息内容转消息对象
                Messages messages = JSON.parseObject(message, Messages.class);
                // 发送消息
                sendP2PMessage(messages.getReceiveUid(), message);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("WebSocket消息异常:", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(@PathParam(value = "uid") String uid) {
        friendsList.remove(friendsList.stream().filter((friends -> friends.getUid().equals(uid))).findAny().orElse(null));
        webSocketSession.remove(uid);
        // 通知更新好友信息列表
        updateFriendInformationList();
        log.info("【WebSocket消息】客户端[{}]连接断开, 剩余连接总数:{}", uid, webSocketSession.size());
    }

    /**
     * 点对点发送
     */
    public static synchronized void sendP2PMessage(String uid, String message) {
        log.info("【WebSocket消息】点对点发送消息, uid={} , message={}", uid, message);
        try {
            webSocketSession.get(uid).session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("点对点发送异常:", e);
        }
    }


}
```

```
package com.chat.imbackend.entity;


import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.*;
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@TableName("tbl_users")
public class User {

    @TableId(type = IdType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    String uid;

    String nickname;

    String password;

    String avatar = "src/assets/Resource/avatar/defaultAvatar.png";

    @TableField(fill = FieldFill.INSERT)
    Date jtime;


}
```

```
package com.chat.imbackend.mapper;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper;
import com.chat.imbackend.entity.User;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;


@Mapper
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<User> {

    @Select("select * from tbl_users where uid= #{uid}")
    User getUserByUid(@Param("uid") String uid);



    @Update("UPDATE tbl_users SET nickname = #{nickname} WHERE uid = #{uid}")
    void modifyUser(@Param("uid") String uid, @Param("nickname") String nickname);

    @Update("UPDATE tbl_users SET avatar = #{avatar} WHERE uid = #{uid}")
    void modifyAvatar(@Param("uid") String uid, @Param("avatar") String avatar);

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbbm.png)

I found this. My userMapper in this class is null. Why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/300g0.png)

Comment: I would recommend changing your log levels to DEBUG for spring and myBatis. Also are all myBatis configuration correctly configured? are you sure your application is even connected with the database? Side note, the `avatar` attribute looks to have a relative path, if your application is built into a jar, that wont work as that path does not exist within an application the file is compressed within the jar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply My application is able to communicate with the database and I have called this function from other backend interfaces, but it returns information instead of null.